# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) - Is it possible get conversion count defined by Japanese?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to get the count for each conversion of google analytics 4 by **google-analytics-data-api** and **google python client library**.

However, when I set the Japanese conversion name as metrics I get the error bellow.

ERROR Message:
`google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Metric names must only contain letters, numbers, or _. Received a metric name = conversions[日本語コンバージョン名称1]`

The code is bellow

```
 client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()    
 metrics_all = ["conversions:日本語コンバージョン名称1"]
 metrics_request = [Metric(name=metrics) for metrics in metrics_all]
 
 request = RunReportRequest(
            property=f"properties/{property_id}",
            dimensions=[Dimension(name="firstUserSource"),
                        Dimension(name="firstUserMedium"),
                        Dimension(name="firstUserCampaignName")],
            metrics=metrics_request,
            date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-07-01", end_date="2023-07-02")],
           )
 response = client.run_report(request)
```

I got the metric by the get_metadata method bellow.
https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data/blob/main/samples/snippets/get_common_metadata.py

Is it possible to get conversion count defined by japanese?
I want to know the way.

Comment: Where did you create these  Japanese conversion name exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I confirm the member who creates those however I don't create those.

Comment: Those Convesrion event was registered in Admin Setting of Google Analytics 4.
It likely is impossible to request the conversion event including Japanese.

Comment: This time, by making a request as follows, we will specify all conversion metrics, and we were able to obtain CV metrics including Japanese.

・Dimension: sourceMedium, campaignName, eventName
・Metrics: conversions

Being unfamiliar with GA4, I had a hard time coming up with the idea of putting the event name in the dimension.

Comment: So you created a custom dimension using Japanese characters?  the parameter_name actually contains Japanese characters.   Let me just ping the team on this one. I wonder if they have that documented or not.

Comment: Yes I heard the member created a custom event and conversion using Japanese characters.